# Changing the index of the sums when changing the sums - why this way?

Tags: proof-verification, summation, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov chain with state space $E$. For $i,j\in E$ set
$$
h_i(j):=\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)<\infty):=\mathbb{P}(H(j)<\infty|X_o=i),
$$
where $H(j)\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{N}_0\cup\left\{\infty\right\}, \omega\mapsto\inf\left\{n\geq 0: X_n(\omega)=j\right\}$.

> > Show that for $i,j,k\in E$ it is 
> >     $$
> > h_i(k)\geq h_i(j)\cdot h_j(k).
> > $$

Ok, here is what I made up to now using the definition of conditional probability and the strong Markov property:

\begin{align}
h_i(k)&=\mathbb{P}_i(H(k)<\infty)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_i(H(k)=n)\\
&\geq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_i(H(k)=n,H(j)\leq n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\mathbb{P}_i(H(k)=n,H(j)=\ell)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\mathbb{P}_i(H(k)=n|H(j)=\ell)\cdot\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)=\ell)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^n \mathbb{P}_j(H(k)=n-\ell)\cdot\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)=\ell)
\end{align}

Now because of absolute convergence one can exchange the sums. But I am not sure how to adapt the index of the sums; I think it is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^n \mathbb{P}_j(H(k)=n-\ell)\cdot\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)=\ell)&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=\ell}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_j(H(k)=n-\ell)\cdot\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)=\ell)~~~~(*)\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)=\ell)\sum_{n=\ell}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_j(H(k)=n-\ell)\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)=\ell)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_j(H(k)=n)\\
&=\mathbb{P}_i(H(j)<\infty)\cdot\mathbb{P}_j(H(k)<\infty)\\&=h_i(j)\cdot h_j(k).
\end{align}

---

1.) Am I right resp. is my proof okay?

2.) I did the index adaption in line $(*)$ more intuitively. Could you please tell me how I formally get from
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^n\ldots\text{ to }\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=\ell}^{\infty}\ldots?
$$

*With greetings*

Comment: For 2) In general, if you want to interchange sums, you need to check absolute convergence.  You're okay here because everything's positive (as long at it converges), so you can realize both sums as sums over the same index set {$(n, \ell): 0 \le \ell \le n < \infty$}.

Comment: I think the absolute convergence simply follows by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^n\lvert P_j(H(k)=n-\ell)P_i(H(j)=\ell)\rvert=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^n P_j(H(k)=n-\ell)P_i(H(j)=\ell)\leqslant h_i(k)\leqslant 1$, or?